# Created symlink over directory

Tags: command-line, 20.04, symbolic-link

I wanted `/usr/bin/local` to symlink to `/home/jonas/swift-5.3.3-RELEASE-ubuntu20.04/usr/bin/swift`, so I entered the following command:

`sudo ln -s swift-5.3.3-RELEASE-ubuntu20.04/usr/bin/swift /usr/bin/local`

Unfortunately now `/usr/bin/local` is a symlink to swift and it's contents are gone, as shown here:

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 Mär 29 13:24 /usr/bin/local -> swift-5.3.3-RELEASE-ubuntu20.04/usr/bin/swift`

Is there any way to heal this?

Comment: I think you might have confused `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/bin`... In my installation, `/usr/bin/local` does not exist.

Comment: that is probably true! ::facepalm::

Comment: Next: by using the command you posted: `ln -s FILE LINK`, you create a link at the path specifief in `LINK`, that links to `FILE`. The link you create is a kind of file itself, but it directs to `FILE`. If there is an existent file or directory located at `LINK`, you would delete it and replace it by your new symlink. So be careful! I think this is not what you want to do. Can you explain what you do want to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a symlink to some local version of Swift and to place that link under `/usr/local/bin`, the solution would be:

```
ln -s swift-5.3.3-RELEASE-ubuntu20.04/usr/bin/swift /usr/local/bin/swift
```

Answer (score 0):

`ln` will not create a symbolic link with the same name as an existing directory. In that case, the syntax will be evaluated as

```
   ln [OPTION]... TARGET... DIRECTORY
```

This means: if `/usr/bin/local` isan existing directory, a link named as the target (target is `swift-5.3.3-RELEASE-ubuntu20.04/usr/bin/swift` so name is  `swift`) will be created in that existing directory.

**Certainly, your `/usr/bin/local` could not be replaced by a similarly named symbolic link if it existed.**

Thus, from your report, we can safely assume that there was no previous `/usr/bin/local` folder on your system. Typically, such folder is not present on a standard linux system. Accordingly, your command created a symbolic link `/usr/bin/local` in `/user/bin`, as you saw for yourself.